# Objective-C Math not returning correct float

Tags: objective-c

I have something like this:

```
int numberOfPages = (float)((float)totalItems / (float)numberOfColumns);
```

totalItems = 60, numberOfColumns = 16, I am expecting numberOfPages to be 3.75, but it returns 3, I need it to be 3.75 so I can round up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because you're trying to store the result in an `int` instead of a `float`.

Comment: true..if you put it into an answer, ill accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer, as requested:  You're doing floating point math, but then assigning the result to an integer:

```
int numberOfPages = (float)((float)totalItems / (float)numberOfColumns);
```

And in C (and derivative languages like Objective-C) floats are converted to integers by dropping whatever's after the decimal point.  You can't round up this way, only down.  You can use `lroundf` to round from a `float` to a (long) `int` directly:

```
int numberOfPages = lroundf(totalItems / (float)numberOfColumns);
```

Note that you do not need to explicitly cast both operands of `/` to `float`.  If one operand is a `float` then the compiler will promote the other operand, and the result will also be a `float`.